# How can I put together an array and a list and filter the list base on the values of the array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Here's the thing, I have two arrays. One is a list of names and the other are values. I want to put them together and filter all names where the values are higher than zero.

How can I do this?

Something like this, the array is the list of coefficients from a regression, just like this:

```
array([-0.1,  0.82105695,  0, 0, 10])
```

The list is the name of the columns:

```
Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
  dtype='object', length=1000)
```

I want the result to be the list of columns with values higher than 0. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a `for` loop that is the same length of the values list, and then check if the value is higher then zero. If the value is higher then zero use `.remove()` or `.pop()` in order to delete the name of the column from the columns list.
(I hope I understand  your question...)

Something like this:

```
for i in len(values_array):
    if values_array[i-1] > 0:
        columns_array.pop(i-1)
```